# Redirect by receiving Spring MVC ModelAndView from JavaScript fetch API

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Spring MVC controller and Thymeleaf template engine. Now I want to redirect an URL("forward:/endpoint") from JavaScript after MVC controller respond against a request. But redirection will not be done from MVC controller, just it send ModelAndView data. So that Thymeleaf engine can parse this ModelAndView data after redirection happened on success block in fetch api.

My Controller: [If required any modification, please edit my controller code]

```
@PostMapping(path = "/endpoint", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView payLoadProcess(@RequestBody Payload payload, ModelMap model) {
  int value1 = payload.getVal1();
  String value2 =payload.getVal2();

        model.addAttribute("value1", value1);
        model.addAttribute("value2", value2);

    return new ModelAndView("forward:/endpoint", model);
}
```

My Fetch request:

```
let payload = {
        val1: 100,
        val2: 'Some name'
    }

const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/endpoint', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(payload)
});

response.then(json => {
            console.log(json.json())
           // I want to redirect from here and Thymeleaf can parse ModelAndView data.
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Note: fetch request also reach at controller. No problem in here

My HTML template:

```
<h5 th:text="${value1}">value1</h5>
<p th:text="${value2}">Some text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fetch function is able to accept an option in its additional params that makes it follow redirects. Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options

Going by the above documentation, change your fetch to:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/endpoint', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  redirect: 'follow'
});
```